# Find the length of side of equilateral triangle in given circumstances.

Tags: geometry

> In $\triangle ABC$ right angled at $C$, $\angle A =\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and $AC = \sqrt3$, three points $D, E, F$ are taken on sides $AB,BC,CA$ respectively, such that $\triangle DEF$  is equilateral. If $BE= \dfrac12$, then the length of side of triangle DEF is equal to ?

[image]
Using trignometry i have found, $AC=\sqrt3,AB=2,BC=1,CE=EB=\dfrac12$

If $DF=DE=FE=x$ 
then
$CF=\sqrt{x^2-\dfrac14}$

I am looking for a simple/short way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle EDB=\angle CEF=\theta$, now using sine rule in $\triangle BED$:
$$\frac{BE}{\sin (\angle BDE)}=\frac{DE}{\sin(\angle EBD)}\implies \frac{1}{2\sin\theta}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}$$
Now applying again in $\triangle FEC$:
$$\frac{CE}{\sin(\angle CFE)}=\frac{FE}{\sin(\angle FCE)}\implies \frac{1}{2\cos \theta}=\frac{x}{1}$$
Now:
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{4x}\right)^2+\left(\frac1{2x}\right)^2=1$$
So:
$$x=\frac{\sqrt7}{4}$$

Comment: u mean $x=\dfrac{\sqrt7}{4}$

Comment: @RK maybe, is it correct?

Comment: thnks, i m still reading ,it was given $\dfrac{\sqrt7}{4}$.

Comment: r u sure that $\frac{BE}{\sin (\angle BED)}=\frac{DE}{\sin(\angle EBD)}$ or is it $\frac{BD}{\sin (\angle BED)}=\frac{DE}{\sin(\angle EBD)}$

Comment: @RK 'twas a typo, corrected

Comment: I didn't get how, $\sin(\angle CFE)=\cos \theta$ ?

Comment: @RK because $\angle CFE=\pi/2-\theta$. I suggest you find all possible 12[twelve] angles first

Comment: Ok i got it now.